# .NET SSH tunnel - Object of type “System.Net.Sockets.Socket” cannot be converted to object of type “System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener”

Tags: c#, .net, ssh-tunnel

I try to use the code of [chilversc](https://gist.github.com/chilversc/5575617#file-gistfile1-cs-L48) and I get the error message at this line

```
var listener = (TcpListener) typeof (ForwardedPortLocal).GetField ("_listener", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue (port);
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that Gist is based on an older version of SSH.NET.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/bd01d971790a7c1fa73bad35b79ada90bf69e62d/src/Renci.SshNet/ForwardedPortLocal.NET.cs#L20), the error message is expected. `_listener` is a `Socket`, not a `TcpListener`:

```
_listener = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) {NoDelay = true};
```

Actually, I think just changing the cast from `TcpListener` to `Socket` will fix your problem, since `Socket` also has the `LocalEndPoint` property.

```
// Hack to allow dynamic local ports, ForwardedPortLocal should expose _listener.LocalEndpoint
var listener = (Socket)typeof (ForwardedPortLocal).GetField("_listener", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(port);
localPort = ((System.Net.IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndPoint).Port;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get "'Socket' does not contain a definition for 'LocalEndpoint' and no accessible extension method 'LocalEndpoint' accepting a first argument of type 'Socket' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: It's a typo. `Socket` has [`LocalEndPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8#properties) (capital P).

Comment: Oh, yes, "LocalEndpoint" should be "LocalEndPoint". Many thanks!